# webpack exports-loader with jest tests

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs

I have a component which imports Foundation. Since Foundation doesn't export anything I'm using Webpack's exports-loader to allow me to import Foundation. This works fine with Webpack but when running my tests I get an undefined error as Jest doesn't know how to import the file.

Is there anything similar to Webpack's exports-loader for Jest?